# VNC connection doesnt show toolbar

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, vnc

I am trying to connect my windows 10 computer with a ubuntu16.04 by a vnc by following [this introduction](https://www.snel.com/support/install-vnc-ubuntu-16-04/).

I'm able to conect but what I see there is not very usefull, since I only see one folder opend where I can navigate and open files. But I'm not able to open a terminal nor anything else. Like you can see in the screenshot.

Does somebody knows how to realy get use of the vnc, like I'm really using it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: And if you move the scroll down, what will you see? empty window?

Comment: Try setting up on Ubuntu https://tigervnc.org/
in any case, I use it and everything works for me.

Comment: Scrolling only shows more of the background. Where I'm able to right click and select 'Open a terminal' but nothing happens...

Comment: I'll gibt tigervnc a try.